# 404 error when importing npm yaml package into Rails 7

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

I'm trying to import the `yaml` npm package into a Rails 7 app; but, I appear to be missing a step.  When I attempt to load a page that imports this package, I get this 404:

```
Started GET "/_/9e35e2fa.js" for ::1 at 2023-08-28 09:56:58 -0400
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/_/9e35e2fa.js"):
```

When I look in the network tab of the developer tools, I see that the initiator of this file is `yaml-c3a2c347f0aeaabd61d2e4bfa7779882d85af0a207269ec0727fd8c981c75a4a.js`

To add this npm package, I did the following:

- `npm install yaml`
- `./bin/importmap pin yaml --download`
- `restart the server (development)`

Am I missing a step?

I'm using Rails 7.0.7 and Ruby 3.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using importmaps, `npm install yaml` is not involved in that. You shouldn't download pinned packages by default, it almost defeats the purpose of importmaps. CDN for other people's stuff, local files for your stuff.

```bash
# undo your download, make sure it's not in vendor/javascript
$ bin/importmap unpin yaml

# pin to the url
$ bin/importmap pin yaml
Pinning "yaml" to https://ga.jspm.io/npm:yaml@2.3.1/browser/index.js
```

Either they meant for it to work that way, or they missed a file. But that relative import `/_/9e35e2fa.js` has to be relative to jspm, which should work fine now:
*https://ga.jspm.io/npm:yaml@2.3.1/_/9e35e2fa.js*

---

**Update**

Once you open the page once, everything is cached in browser, just don't hard reload or clear cache.

But you can also fix yaml package to work when you download it:

```rb
# config/importmap.rb

if Rails.env.production?
  pin "yaml", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:yaml@2.3.1/browser/index.js"
else
  pin "yaml" # @2.3.1
  pin "/_/9e35e2fa.js", to: "9e35e2fa.js"
end
```

```bash
bin/importmap pin yaml --download
wget -P vendor/javascript/ https://ga.jspm.io/npm:yaml@2.3.1/_/9e35e2fa.js
```

Comment: Does that mean that the app will pull yaml from the CDN in production also? (In other words, will my app depend on the CDN being up?)

Comment: @Zack yes and yes. however, don't think "depend", think "offload". ok there was an 11min downtime this year) https://status.jspm.io/

Comment: I have been trying to do some development work on the bus (without internet). When I do, I get this error:  `GET https://ga.jspm.io/npm:yaml@2.3.1/browser/index.js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` Is there a way to grab the library locally in development even if it uses the CDN in production?